# Identifying outliers in sets of three measurements

Tags: outliers

I have a number of individuals with three measurements for each individual. In a normal individual I expect all three measurements to be roughly the same, but between individuals they can vary a lot. I'm looking for points that are outliers within individuals, not between them.

I'm not sure how to do this though. I considered making radar plots or perhaps taking the average of two scores for each individual and plotting them against the third score, but neither of these seems ideal. Radar plots could get messy with the number of individuals I'm looking at, and the latter method forces me to combine data from multiple plots (i.e. the average of A and B vs C, the average of A and C vs B, and the average of B and C vs A) to identify which of the three measurements is the outlier, or go back to the data to check it.

Do you guys have any suggestions? I'm open to graphical methods or statistical tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate standardized values for each of the three measures. This will scale each of the three measures in terms of individual-level standard deviations away from the mean.

$x_A^* = \frac{x_A - \bar{x}}{s}$

$x_B^* = \frac{x_B - \bar{x}}{s}$

$x_C^* = \frac{x_C - \bar{x}}{s}$

Then, you can query on $\pm$1, 2, etc., standard deviations from the mean for each measurement.

Here's a concrete example in R using the iris data.

```
D <- iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")]
D$rowMean <- rowMeans(D)
D$rowSD <- apply(D, 1, sd)
D$Sepal.Length.Std <- (D$Sepal.Length - D$rowMean) / D$rowSD
D$Sepal.Width.Std <- (D$Sepal.Width - D$rowMean) / D$rowSD
D$Petal.Length.Std <- (D$Petal.Length - D$rowMean) / D$rowSD
threshold <- 1.39
D$Sepal.Length.Outlier <- abs(D$Sepal.Length.Std) > threshold
D$Sepal.Width.Outlier <- abs(D$Sepal.Width.Std) > threshold
D$Petal.Length.Outlier <- abs(D$Petal.Length.Std) > threshold
D$anyOutliers <- apply(D[, c("Sepal.Length.Outlier", "Sepal.Width.Outlier", "Petal.Length.Outlier")], 1, any)
```

The 5 "individuals" with any outliers are:

```
> D[D$anyOutliers == TRUE, ]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length  rowMean    rowSD Sepal.Length.Std Sepal.Width.Std Petal.Length.Std Sepal.Length.Outlier
99           5.1         2.5          3.0 3.533333 1.126450        1.3908004      -0.9173364       -0.4734640                 TRUE
101          6.3         3.3          6.0 5.200000 1.349074        0.8153742      -1.4083737        0.5929995                FALSE
107          4.9         2.5          4.5 3.966667 1.049868        0.8890009      -1.3970014        0.5080005                FALSE
119          7.7         2.6          6.9 5.733333 2.239544        0.8781551      -1.3990946        0.5209395                FALSE
135          6.1         2.6          5.6 4.766667 1.545603        0.8626622      -1.4018261        0.5391639                FALSE
    Sepal.Width.Outlier Petal.Length.Outlier anyOutliers
99                FALSE                FALSE        TRUE
101                TRUE                FALSE        TRUE
107                TRUE                FALSE        TRUE
119                TRUE                FALSE        TRUE
135                TRUE                FALSE        TRUE
```

Comment: Is the idea that I'm looking for measurements that are too far from the mean or that I'm looking for measurements that are farther away from the mean than the other two measurements for that subject.  It seems like the former has me looking for outliers between, not within, individuals, but the latter leaves me with the same question: how do I identify which (if any) measurement in each individual is an outlier?  Thanks for the answer -- sorry if I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: I'll edit with a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks -- I get it now! I'm going to give it a try and then mark it as solved if it works. I'm afraid my +1 isn't showing up because I'm new to the site and don't have enough reputation, but it should appear eventually.